# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser How to handle 401 requests so I can refresh my Oauth2 token for the browser

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

CefSharp version 83.4.20.0

We're using ChromiumWebBrowser in our Winform Application and used this resource to build the basics. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample.

The browser calls our API which uses OAuth2 authentication and the token expires after about 20mins.

What I want to be able to do is on the next click or a refresh of the browser, if there is a 401 error returned in the response, I want to update the ChromiumWebBrowser object with the new token and resume browsing on the current URL.

I've tried using the LoadError event, and I've tried creating a custom RequestHandler but can't seem to trigger the events.

LoadError code sample:

```
    private void InitialiseBrowser()
    {
        _ds = _svc.Get((long)_command);

        if (_ds == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ds.Url))
        {
            XtraMessageBox.Show($"Not implemented or website doesn't exist for {_command.ToString()}", "Error - Can't find the Web Page", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        _webBrowserUrlDS = _restAPIService.GetUrl(_ds.Url);

        // Create a browser component
        _browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser(_webBrowserUrlDS.GetUrl());
     
        _browser.IsBrowserInitializedChanged += OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged;
        _browser.TitleChanged += OnBrowserTitleChanged;
        _browser.AddressChanged += OnBrowserAddressChanged;

        _browser.BrowserSettings = new BrowserSettings { LocalStorage = CefState.Disabled };

        string cacheFolderPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), @"CefSharp\");

        if (!Directory.Exists(cacheFolderPath))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(cacheFolderPath);

        RequestContextSettings requestContextSettings = new RequestContextSettings
        {
            CachePath = cacheFolderPath,
            PersistSessionCookies = true,
            PersistUserPreferences = true
        };

        _browser.RequestContext = new RequestContext(requestContextSettings);
        _browser.RequestHandler = new MyRequestHandler();
        
        _browser.DownloadHandler = new DownloadHandler();
        _browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        _browser.LoadError += _browser_LoadError;
    }
    
    private void _browser_LoadError(object sender, LoadErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => LoadUrl());
    }

    private void LoadUrl()
    {
        _webBrowserUrlDS = _restAPIService.GetUrl(_ds.Url);

        _browser.Load(_webBrowserUrlDS.GetUrl());
    }
```

```html
[1103/172519.920:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(185)] 2693E538: set chrome proxy config service to 2693E7E0
[1103/172519.954:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(119)] Could not get the download directory.
[1103/172523.278:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(1164)] Failed configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
[1103/173529.114:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(185)] 2909DD78: set chrome proxy config service to 290A0130
[1103/173529.391:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 8
[1103/173529.413:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.414:VERBOSE1:simple_index_file.cc(600)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
[1103/173529.481:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(153)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[1103/173529.491:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(119)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  5BF41BA8
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[1103/173529.491:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(119)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[1103/173529.491:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(372)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[1103/173529.659:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/60000002509.js
[1103/173529.663:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "token: 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", source: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/main-es2015.1e468f784758128c5008.js (2)
[1103/173529.664:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "target page: inspection", source: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/main-es2015.1e468f784758128c5008.js (2)
[1103/173529.664:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[object Object]", source: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/main-es2015.1e468f784758128c5008.js (2)
[1103/173529.665:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev-api.netstrata.com.au/security/validatesinglesignon?token=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
[1103/173529.702:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/bootstrap.js
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.708:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173529.716:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgets/60000002509.json?randomId=0.7282822256917936
[1103/173529.832:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.005:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.023:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.024:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.320:VERBOSE1:configured_proxy_resolution_service.cc(1164)] Failed configuring with PAC script, falling-back to manual proxy servers.
[1103/173530.518:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "[object Object]", source: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/main-es2015.1e468f784758128c5008.js (2)
[1103/173530.555:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.555:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.564:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.32611135213598397
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.574:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.589:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.703:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.738:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.755:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.755:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.772:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.772:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.788:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.805:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.822:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.839:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.856:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.907:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/static/media/frame.d7ae132c.css
[1103/173530.913:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(153)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[1103/173530.913:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(119)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  5BF53D88
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[1103/173530.914:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(119)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[1103/173530.914:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(372)] Num tracked contexts: 2
[1103/173530.916:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.931:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/widget.js
[1103/173530.956:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173530.958:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/0.96c1c69b8724e56254b8.widget.js
[1103/173530.958:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/1.8bd0d39ed40ee0109589.widget.js
[1103/173530.958:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/8.391e72735dac0c934b81.widget.js
[1103/173530.960:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/10.2e5460d4c197a23f9b8f.widget.js
[1103/173530.961:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/16.7514a03efa63da04b832.widget.js
[1103/173530.965:VERBOSE1:v8_context_snapshot.cc(153)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[1103/173530.966:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(119)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  5BF56638
  URL:                    
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[1103/173530.966:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(119)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                    
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[1103/173530.966:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(372)] Num tracked contexts: 3
[1103/173530.971:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/static/media/styles.5fe92f64.css
[1103/173530.980:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://widget.freshworks.com/widgetBase/locales/en.json
[1103/173531.260:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/ngsw-worker.js
[1103/173535.858:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.870:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.887:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.904:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.909:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.024518136419904968
[1103/173535.920:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.937:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.953:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.970:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173535.986:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.000:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.8664211672570943
[1103/173536.003:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.020:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.037:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.054:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.071:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.087:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.103:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.120:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.137:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173536.153:ERROR:paint_controller.cc(646)] PaintController::FinishCycle() completed
[1103/173606.052:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1392)] [state:51CDC000] CollectGarbage: time: 3.2ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: EagerSweeping reason: ThreadTerminationGC
[1103/173606.053:VERBOSE1:thread_state.cc(1392)] [state:51CDC000] CollectGarbage: time: 0.048ms stack: NoHeapPointersOnStack marking: AtomicMarking sweeping: EagerSweeping reason: ThreadTerminationGC
[1103/173630.562:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Checking for updates at 0 minutes", source: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/main-es2015.1e468f784758128c5008.js (2)
[1103/173630.583:VERBOSE1:simple_index_file.cc(600)] Simple Cache Index is being restored from disk.
[1103/173630.591:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.2179077106672751
[1103/173635.591:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://smata-dev.netstrata.com.au/ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.021386362320293673
```

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide detailed code example of what you have tried already.

Comment: Hi @amaitland I've added a code sample for the most relevant information. Adding the custom RequestHandler wasn't too relevant as it was as bare bones as it is and only had borrowed code from the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49667634/winforms-cefsharp-authentication-popup-for-basic-authentication-not-show

Comment: I'm surprised 401 isn't triggering LoadError, have you tried removing all your other code and just hooking the loaderror event. Basically start with the minimal example,  add the event handler and see if it's called.

Comment: See if http://cefsharp.github.io/api/85.3.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_ResourceRequestHandler_OnResourceResponse.htm has a response statuscode of 401.

Comment: A quick check and it would appear that 401 isn't calling LoadError (testing with https://httpbin.org/status/401). Loading chrome://network-errors/ and picking any error it is called as expected. So this would be a problem with the `Chromium Embedded Framework(CEF)` and how it handles 4xx error codes.

Comment: Thanks @amaitland. Is there any event I can use to handle a bad request? Anything in RequestHandler that would do the job. This problem arises because in our application we currently have only one place in the app where the chromium browser can be accessed. So a user might start the app, and if in the next 20mins they don't access the chromium browser then they won't be able to view the page because the SSO Token has expired.

Comment: I also find that if I get the single sign on token error, if I try to refresh the token (which works fine) when I try to call the ChromiumWebBrowser.Load() method it doesn't load the page, it's just blank/white. Calling ChromiumWebBrowser.RefreshBrowser after that doesn't help either.

Comment: Is http://cefsharp.github.io/api/85.3.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_ResourceRequestHandler_OnResourceResponse.htm called with a 401? See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-interception for a slightly different example,  override  OnresourceResponse instead of GetResourceHandler check the log file for errors

Comment: Re: your first link to ResourceRequestHandler.OnResourceResponse. I tested that today and found that when using the dev tools the status code is 400, but the IRestResponse.StatusCode is 200. I was using this link for the sample code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124372/cefsharp-how-can-i-access-onresourceresponse-from-build-75-1-143

Comment: Managed to get a Browser Refresh functionality working via a click event on a button. Had to call all these methods in order for it to work consistently. 

`_browser.Load(_currentAddress);
_browser.BringToFront();
_browser.Refresh();
_browser.Reload(false);`

But I'd still like to be able to handle the response so that if it is a 400 or 401 I can refresh the token.

Comment: Did you check the log file? Rather than hacking at it, really should understand what's going on. BringTofFront and Refresh should have no bearing on loading webpages

Comment: Hi @amaitland, I've added a snippet of the log file when it fails to the question above. If you need I can paste a snippet of a successful refresh if that helps.

Comment: I understand what you mean about understanding what is going on. But the main issue I see is for the developer tools the status code is 400, but the IRestResponse.StatusCode is 200. Cef isn't picking up the 4xx errors as you said. So there's no way for me to handle them.

Comment: Using https://httpbin.org/status/401 to simulate a 401, using version 85 and I see a `StatusCode` of 401 as expected in `OnResourceLoadComplete`. How does https://httpbin.org/status/401 behave when you execute it?

Comment: Same as before. 200 in OnResourceResponse and 401 in dev tools

Comment: Have you tested In version 85?